# Power NodeMCU with 12v to 5v 3a - 15w DC-DC Converter?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter, nodemcu

I want to power a NodeMCU and a LED Strip with 12v power supply. I don’t want to risk doing anything to the NodeMCU though so I want to convert the 12v to 5v. I have already tried a LM7805 but it gets way too hot to even touch slightly. Would a DC-DC converter like this work okay to convert to 5v? https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Better-Waterproof-DC-DC-Converter-12V-Step-Down-to-5V-Car-Power-Supply-Module-3A/281296554356?epid=2100111522&hash=item417e94c974:g:3ioAAOxyUI1TGV9B
It’s the cheapest alternative I could find to an LM7805 so I’m curious if it would work just fine.
Thank you.

Comment: overkill, you can get bucks for $0.50usd with enough current for the ESP, which you actually want to feed 3.3v instead of 5v to save more heat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it should work fine. It seems overkill if you don't need waterproof and 3A of current.

If you are just looking for something cheap that works I did a quick search and found this: https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/DC-4-5-24V-to-DC-3V-15V-5V-9V-12V-1-2A-Buck-Converter-Step-down-Power-Regulator/332359897940?hash=item4d62319354:g:oZgAAOSwUT5ZlbW3

Either should work fine you can check their output voltage with a voltmeter before you connect it to the load.

Comment: Thank you, thats good to know as there is one going for quite a low price in an auction.